# Symbol to denote a group which is either an oxygen atom or NH group

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, notation

I'm drawing the generic structure of several different organic molecules in my thesis. They share some features, one of which is a carbonyl carbon attached to either an oxygen atom (i.e. ester) or an $\ce{-NH}$ (i.e. amide).

My first instinct was to draw it like this<sup>†</sup>: $\ce{R-X-C(=O)-R'}$

But I wonder if X wrongly implies that it's a halogen? In which case, what would be the correct letter or symbol to use? I've seen Z used sometimes when X is used elsewhere, would that be more appropriate? Or perhaps Q for heteroatom, as in Reaxys? Or A for 'any'?

<sup>†</sup> I'm actually drawing in ChemDraw, this is simplified for the sake of the question

Edit: corrected mistake (nitrogen atom -> $\ce{-NH}$ group)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oxygen and nitrogen have different valencies, so you can't use the same letter to denote literally an $\ce{O}$ or an $\ce{N}$ atom, as they can't be directly substituted for one another.

You should use the same letter to denote $\ce{O}$ or $\ce{NH}$, for example. It's perfectly permissible to write $\ce{R-X-C(O)-R'}$ and say $\ce{X} = \ce{O}, \ce{NH}$. This approach is commonly used in the literature. If your amide is tertiary then write something like $\ce{X} = \ce{O}, \ce{NH}, \ce{NR}$. The same applies to structures drawn in ChemDraw.

Beyond that, the choice of letter is arbitrary (*as long as you define it!*) so $\ce{X}$ is perfectly fine, although you should obviously avoid letters which already represent a chemical element (e.g. $\ce{B}$, $\ce{C}$, ...).

What one might consider the "official rules" are given in: Brecher, J. Graphical representation standards for chemical structure diagrams (IUPAC Recommendations 2008). *Pure and Applied Chemistry* **2008,** *80* (2), 277–410. DOI: [10.1351/pac200880020277](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277) (free version provided [here](http://publications.iupac.org/pac/pdf/2008/pdf/8002x0277.pdf)). See especially section GR-2.2. However, there isn't really much in there that constrains you; a lot of it is "common sense".

Comment: Of course I meant NH and feel very silly now... Edited my question for the sake of future readers. Thank you for the excellent answer!